# Is there any Google Cloud Platform functionality like Azure's "Export ARM Template"?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code

I am new to GCP, but I have used AWS and Azure extensively.

## Background

In Azure, there is a functionality to [export an ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal). There are several ways to use this, but as a beginner, it is a *great* way to put together the architecture that I need / want via the GUI, then export it to a JSON / YAML format so that I have some idea what the Infra-as-Code will need to look like as I convert it to Terraform and/or [Google Config Connector](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/overview).

## Question

Is there any way to export the current project into a template so that I can use the template as a starting point for creating infra as code?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/export

Comment: Great, thanks!  Is there any equivalent for exporting to Config Connector, too?  Maybe there will be some day...